# Dynamically generated SSL sites

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, tomcat, ssl, amazon-route53

I am building a system on AWS for my client. The client's customers will be able to access a login page and create their own EC2 instance. This EC2 instance will be pre configured with Tomcat and my client's war file auto deployed. The users will be able to access the web application from the ip address. For e.g. Lets say User A logs onto a portal. Clicks on create instance. An instance gets auto provisioned with a URL (like http://18.xx.xx.xx/MyApplication). User A will be able to do a whole bunch of activities on this web site.
Now, is there any way that I can dynamically enable SSL on these. I would need to generate SSL certificates on the fly and attach it to the URL. Ideally UserA should be able to access https://18.xx.xx.xx/MyApplication. Self signed certificates will not cut the ice. This might be rudimentary, but I have limited knowledge on SSL. Any help/tips/links to URLs would be greatly appreciated.

For additional clarity - these instances will not be clustered. User A will have his own instance and his own application. User B will have his own instance and his own application. User A and User B's instances will not be clustered. I need to ensure that User A's instance when created has SSL enabled automatically.
Cheers!
VJ

Answer (score 1):

You may want to setup a DNS with hostnames for each instance. Maybe hostnames like 18-xxx-xxx-xxx.yourdomain.com where "18-xxx-xxx-xxx" is the IP address with `-` instead of `.`.

For such hostnames you can generate and renew [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) certificates programatically. There exist programs in standard linux repos for generating Let's Encrypt certificates. You cannot generate certificates for IPs. That's why you have to setup hostnames in the first place.

Now you just have to setup the certificate for your Tomcat (programatically).

Comment: *"You cannot generate certificates for IPs"* using Let's Encrypt or any other public CA is 100% correct.

Answer (score 0):

There's several solutions from AWS that can work for this case, revolving around CloudFormation specifically.

For pre-configured Tomcat and WAR file, and even application, you can create a custom AMI. 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AMIs.html

For each deployment, you can use a CloudFormation template to automate provisioning of this AMI.

For SSL, with some CloudFormation templating, you can include an AWS ALB that listens on HTTPS and targets the new server on each deployment. Also, you can provision the new certificate and attach it to the LB.

Here's the useful links:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-certificatemanager-certificate.html

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-elasticloadbalancingv2-listener-certificates.html

Comment: Thanks. However let me clarify. These instances will not be clustered. For e.g. User A has his own instance and his own Server. User B has his own instance and his own server. Hence when an instance for User A needs to be provisioned, the access will be only for him and needs to be SSL enabled. I already use cloudformation for automatically provisioning tomcat and the war file, I am stuck on the auto generation of ssl certificates.

Comment: Maybe you can abstract SSL from the app server and move it to the load balancer. And use CF + ACM to provision the certificate dynamically. Do you control the DNS routes?